# display processed form php results in original page where form was executed

Tags: php

I am using a simple form to set the name of a hashtag into a php file but I want the results to be displayed on the same page as the form.
My form and php is as follows

```
    <form id"search" method="post" action="twitter.php">
    <input type="text" name="hash" id="hash"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

My php displays the results of a hash tag search

```
    <?php
    global $total, $hashtag;
    $hashtag = $_POST["hash"];
    $total = 0;
    function getTweets($hash_tag, $page) {
    global $total, $hashtag;
    $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='.urlencode($hash_tag).'&';
    $url .= 'page='.$page;    
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $json = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo "<pre>";    
    $json_decode = json_decode($json);
    print_r($json_decode->results);

    $json_decode = json_decode($json);        
    $total += count($json_decode->results);    
    if($json_decode->next_page){
     $temp = explode("&",$json_decode->next_page);        
     $p = explode("=",$temp[0]);                
     getTweets($hashtag,$p[1]);
      }        
    }
  echo $total;
  getTweets($hashtag,1);
    ?>
```

What should I do to get the results of the php to display on the same page as below the form
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post it to the same page, you define an action in your form "twitter.php" this means the form will go to the page twitter.php with the post information.

If you post it to the same page, catch the post request there and display whatever was requested there either below or above the form both elements are shown on the page.

Small example:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && !empty($_POST['hashtag'])) {
    echo "You searched for: " . $_POST['hashtag'] . "!";
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    Hashtag: <input type="text" name="hashtag" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit hashtag!" />
</form>
```

this will display a form with an input field for the hashtag. the script is posted to the same page, the PHP catches the POST request and displays whatever is searched. Instead you could use this value to retrieve the search action from twitter itself.

Comment: when I try to use this code it get a syntax error. It says its this '{' causing the error but I am unsure what to do about it. Apart from that your method makes complete sense

Comment: I'm sorry I made a minor mistake in the example code I gave you, but it is still example code. You will face these errors, in this case a missing ) often. Maybe looking for some general php tutorials could do you some good

Comment: Yeah found it was just a bracket missing. thanks for all your help